# Responsive issues on embed

Tags: css, embed

Okay so ill explain this as best i can.
I have a booking page widget on my website from simplybooking.
It works great on desktop but does not scale on mobile
This is the page in question : https://www.meetaroundthecampfire.com/bookings-checkout/

So this is the code ive tried to use in the page, to make it responsive

```
<div class="embed-container"><script src='//simplybook.me/v2/widget/widget.js'></script> <script>var widget = new SimplybookWidget({'widget_type':'iframe','url':'https:\/\/meetaroundthecampfire.simplybook.me','theme':'concise','theme_settings':{'timeline_show_end_time':'0','light_font_color':'#ffffff','sb_base_color':'#5a3afd','booking_nav_bg_color':'#ffffff','dark_font_color':'#333333','hide_img_mode':'0','sb_busy':'#dad2ce','sb_available':'#d3e0f1'},'timeline':'modern','datepicker':'top_calendar','is_rtl':false,'app_config':{'predefined':[]}});</script></div>
```

With the following css in the stylesheet

```
.embed-container { padding-bottom: 20%; padding-top: 20%; overflow: scroll; max-width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 90%; }
```

But it still doesnt come up right?

Any ideas or help from you legends? because im confused!

Cheers
Ez

Comment: you can use media queries.. here's the link https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 1):

You have width 1800px at:

```
#main2 {
    margin: 0 auto 30px;
    width: 1800px;
}
```

You should edit this with media queries. Put it by default with 100%, and then with queries change it correspondingly. Example:

```
//default
#main2 {
    margin: 0 auto 30px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

For devices > 768px:

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
    #main2 {
       width: 750px;
    }
}
```

etc. etc...

Comment: worked perfect! thankyou so much mate, much appreicated

Comment: Great, I'm glad I helped :)